# Question on "On the Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies"

Tags: special-relativity

In his paper on special relativity, ["On the Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies](http://hermes.ffn.ub.es/luisnavarro/nuevo_maletin/Einstein_1905_relativity.pdf)", Einstein considers two coordinate systems, one that is "stationary", called $k$, with coordinates $(x, \, y, \, z, \,t)$ and one that is moving away in the direction of increasing $x$ with speed $v$, with coordinates $(\xi, \,\eta ,\, \zeta,\, \tau)$, called $K$. Einstein states that $\tau$ is a function of $x', \, y, \, z,$, and $t$, where $x' = x - vt$. On page 6, Einstein states:

> An analogous consideration$-$applied to the axes of Y and Z$-$it being borne in mind that light is always propagated along these axes, when viewed from the stationary system, with the velocity $\sqrt{c^2 - v^2}$ gives us
>
> $$\frac{\partial \tau}{\partial y} = 0, \quad \frac{\partial \tau}{\partial z} =0.$$

How does he get this fact that light propagates on the $y-$ and $z-$axes with velocity $\sqrt{c^2-v^2}$?

Comment: I don’t know if this is the right interpretation. But if you imagine a light pulse traveling at such an angle in *k* so that it remains located on the Y axis, say, the measured velocity along Y in *k* is that given just from the Pythagorean theorem. The Y axis is moving in the x direction at speed *v* which is one perpendicular component of the pulse velocity *c*. The other perpendicular component is the speed along the Y axis.

Comment: I think that is the correct interpretation. I was imagining the scenario incorrectly.